# Why is my activation method working twice?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, activation

I am making an account activation method. Everything looks fine. But I think that I am missing something.. my activation method works twice times. I am new in web.

this is my method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Active(string code)
{            
     return Content("Your account Successfully Activated");
}
```

and here is html&jquery code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        Yout Aktivasyon Code:
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="text" id="ActivationCode"/>            
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Active"/>
    </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('form').submit(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action( "Active", "Account")",
                type: "post",
                data: { code: $('#ActivationCode').val() },
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("successful\n" + result);
                },

                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I put a put a breakpoint in Active method and check "code" parameter. When I submit my form, Active method triggers and code has value that what is in textbox. and I push F5 to continue, after that Active method triggers again and code value is null

I cant find out my mistake why it works twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be that you are doing an ajax request and a normal post after, because you are not preventing the default behavior. Try preventing the default behavior:

```
$(function () {

    $('form').submit(function (e) { // Add the event parameter -> e

        // Prevent the default behavior.
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action( "Active", "Account")",
            type: "post",
            data: { code: $('#ActivationCode').val() },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("successful\n" + result);
            },

            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });

        // Also return false for the default behavior.
        return false;
    });
});
```

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

> event.preventDefault()
>   If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Returning `false` is also a way to tell the event to not actually fire.

Comment: ohh that works perfectly!! I got this message "successful
Your account Successfully Activated"  in browser console :)) and could you explain preventing means? thank you

Comment: I completly understand it, thank you so much for your attention :)

Answer (score 1):

When you pushing F5 you are refreshing content of window received by last request. In your case it was POST sent to 'Account/Active' action. But I suspecting the data (content of textbox) was not sent at the second try.

Open network console of browser (for IE9 - press F12, go to Network tab and push 'Start capturing') and check body of request sent to server. I will not winder if data sending only on the first attempt.

Comment: he yes I tried it and posted just one time. But I realize that             error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log("error");
 works :S I mean an error occurs